# Qt 5.2 + iOS: Playing Video with QMediaPlayer and QVideoWidget

Tags: c++, ios, qt, qt5, qmediaplayer

I've set up a small project in the folder "iosVideoTest/" to play a video in a Qt/iOS app:

iosVideoTest.pro:

```
QT       += core gui multimedia multimediawidgets
QTPLUGIN += qavfmediaplayer
CONFIG   += mobility
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET   = iosVideoTest
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES  += main.cpp
HEADERS  +=
deployment.files  = ../iosVideoTest/media/9d0386eada217cd63a752458aeca89d6.mp4
deployment.path   =
QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += deployment
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QVideoWidget>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow w;
    QVideoWidget* pVWidget = new QVideoWidget;
    QMediaPlayer* pPlayer = new QMediaPlayer;
    // with the following line a video is playing
    pPlayer->setMedia(QUrl("http://www.rmh.de/9d0386eada217cd63a752458aeca89d6/9d0386eada217cd63a752458aeca89d6.mp4"));
    // either of the following lines renders only a black screen
    // pPlayer->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "9d0386eada217cd63a752458aeca89d6.mp4"));
    // pPlayer->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("9d0386eada217cd63a752458aeca89d6.mp4"));
    pPlayer->setVideoOutput(pVWidget);
    w.setCentralWidget(pVWidget);
    w.show();
    pPlayer->play();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I've copied the video http://www.rmh.de/9d0386eada217cd63a752458aeca89d6/9d0386eada217cd63a752458aeca89d6.mp4 to the ./media directory in the project folder.

Using the web URL of the video works.
However, bundling the video inside the app and using the local file name only renders a black screen.

EDIT: Using an image (located at ./iosVideoTest/media/img.png), bundling it via QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA and using it as a local file with an QLabel/QPixmap works like a charm …

Can anybody point me in the right direction to use local video files?

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Have you checked the paths?  Check to make sure the file exists before using the local url.  I know on OSX Mavericks, Apple changed how their paths worked where it defaults to the root.

Comment: Yap. Using local image files that way works well. -- But thanks phyatt for pointing that out. I've just added a note about that.

Comment: Have you tried converting the video to something that is a native format for iTunes, or one that uses more universal codecs?  (Using Handbrake or a similar tool)

Comment: I do not think that it is a codec problem. Using the web URL works.